# "Shell escape not enabled" error, even though write18 is enabled

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot, shell-escape

I have enabled `write18` by telling TeXlipse to call `pdfLaTeX` using the `--enable-write18` option. However, this does not seem to work properly.
The code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}

\begin{document}

\verb|\ifeof18|: 
\ifeof18
    true
\else
    false
\fi

\verb|\pdfshellescape|:
\ifnum\pdfshellescape=1
    true
\else
    false
\fi

\begin{gnuplot}
    plot sin(x), cos(x)
\end{gnuplot}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[domain = -pi : pi] plot function{sin(x)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

produces the output

[image: \ifeof18: flase, \pdfshellescape: true]

so `write18` seems to indeed be enabled, however instead of producing plots it gives me the errors

```
pdflatex.exe> Package pgf Warning: Plot data file `document.pgf-plot.table' not found.

pdflatex.exe> Package gnuplottex Warning: Shell escape not enabled.
pdflatex.exe> (gnuplottex)                You'll need to convert the graphs yourself..

pdflatex.exe> Package gnuplottex Warning: Please convert document-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot manually.
```

What did I do wrong and how can I fix this?

---

PS: gnuplot is installed and calling it from the command line works fine.

---

**Edit:**

I found the following occurences of `runsystem` in the log file:

```
runsystem(touch w18-test-20145301175.tex)...executed.

runsystem(rm -f w18-test-20145301175.tex)...executed.

runsystem(gnuplot document.pgf-plot.gnuplot)...executed.
```

Comment: What TeX distribution are you running? Try `--shell-escape` instead of `--enable-write-18` that's specific of MiKTeX, while the other one should work on every system.

Comment: @egreg: I am using MiKTeX and thus switching to `--shell-escape` didn't do anything. However, I noticed that `\ifeof18` is `false` even without `--shell-escape` (or `--enable-write18`) whereas `pdfshellescape` changes as expected.

Comment: You need to pass the option `miktex`: `\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}`

Comment: `\ifeof18` is false because the restricted shell escape is active. You should report what's near `runsystem` in the log file. But Ulrike's suggestion seems good.

Comment: @Ulrike: That didn't change anything.
@egreg: I added the occurences of `runsystem` in the log file to my question.

Comment: @schtreber Have you added `gnuplot` to system PATH?

Comment: @1010011010: I did.

Comment: The miktex option should change something. I get the warning `Package gnuplottex Warning: Shell escape not enabled.` without it, but not with the option. You problably have a new problem  now. (As gnuplot is not in my path I can't test if your gnuplot command is correct).

Comment: @Ulrike: Damn, you're right. It's still three errors, so I didn't look twice.. So the problem seems to be with gnuplot after all.

Comment: @Ulrike: Would you mind posting this as an answer? I think it's best to ask a separate question about gnuplot, if I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the shell-excape test you need to pass the option `miktex` to gnuplottex:

```
\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}
```